# jFreeChart: How to map String values to axis?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am plotting frequency in Hz, using the TimeSeriesChart. So far so good. But I need to add a second Y (value) axis that would represent musical tones. I need the ticks to be represented by String values (C#9,A4 and so on), so I figured out I should use SymbolAxis. The problem is I need to map the string tick values to exact number values, such as:
A4->440, A#4->466.164, B4->493.883, C5 ->523.251..... So it won't be linear nor logarithmic. How can I do that? Thanks.

(v1.0.17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered [this question](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116864) in the JFreeChart forum already, you could achieve this by subclassing the NumberAxis class and overriding the [refreshTicks()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#refreshTicks%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisState,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge%29) method to return tick labels for specific values only (and with whatever label you require).

Comment: Has there been any new features for manipulating jfreechart axes since the time of this post? The suggested solution seems extremely and unreasonably complex compared with the task of just applying a set of string labels to tick marks that are not spaced along integers. Consider how matplotlib treats axis mark adjustments as a first-class parameter of plotting functions, more similar to `setSeriesPaint` in jfreechart than suggestions about manipulating axes through subclassing. How can users stylize axes without incurring hundreds of lines of boilerplate inheritance code to maintain?